# Unable to download Spring Tool Suite(STS)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite

I am unable to download STS using below link:

https://spring.io/tools/sts/all or  https://spring.io/tools/sts/legacy

I also tried to update my existing eclipse using eclipse market place but facing same issue.

Can anyone suggest me workarounds?

Comment: what exactly do you experience? does that page at https://spring.io/tools/sts/all show up at all?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martin. I think it was problem with link but now I am able to download with the same below link : http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/3.7.2.RELEASE/dist/e4.5/spring-tool-suite-3.7.2.RELEASE-e4.5.1-win32-x86_64.zip

Comment: Glad to hear that you can download the distribution now. Enjoy!